# greatest common factor on objective c

Tags: objective-c, math

I'm new to objective c and I would like to know if there is a method for greatest common factor

`gcf()` for example so you get the idea

Answer (score 8):

There's no out of the box function. Since Objective-C is a superset of C, you can grab an existing library or set of functions and include it where necessary.

Based on http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Programming/data_structures/c/gcd/gcd.c, you might do this:

```
// gcd.h
int gcd(int m, int n);

// gcd.c
int gcd(int m, int n) {

  int t, r;

  if (m < n) {
    t = m;
    m = n;
    n = t;
  }

  r = m % n;

  if (r == 0) {
    return n;
  } else {
    return gcd(n, r);
  }
}
```

Include that file whenever you should wish to use the `gcd` function:

```
#import "gcd.h"
```

Comment: Don't define functions in a header, otherwise if more than one file includes it you will get linking errors.

Answer (score 4):

There is no built in method, but the [Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) is easy to implement, and quite efficient.

[The binary GCD algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm) can be slightly more efficient.  This link has C code implementing it.

Answer (score 3):

By far the most elegant solution I have come across (non-recursive of course):

```
int gcd (int a, int b){
    int c;
    while ( a != 0 ) {
        c = a; a = b%a; b = c;
    }
    return b;
}
```

[Source](http://www.math.wustl.edu/~victor/mfmm/compaa/gcd.c).

Answer (score 0):

Just putting damian86's answer into Objective-C style (reference to `self` assumes context of an object, modify accordingly, you could make this a category, etc):

```
-(int)greatestCommonDivisorM:(int)m N:(int)n
{
    int t, r;

    if (m < n) {
        t = m;
        m = n;
        n = t;
}
    r = m % n;

    if (r == 0) {
        return n;
    } else {
        return [self greatestCommonDivisorM:n N:r];

    }
}
```